# How to manually lock and unlock a row?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, sql-update

I am trying to circumvent double-writes by locking and unlocking certain rows.

I have a table `personnel` and as soon as a user tries to edit a row, I want to lock that row.

So

```
BEGIN;
// I guess I have to lock it somehow here
SELECT * FROM personnel WHERE id = 12;
COMMIT;
```

and once an edit as been made, I want to submit the `UPDATE` in the same style:

```
BEGIN;
//Unlocking
UPDATE personnel SET ...
WHERE id = 12;
COMMIT;
```

In the time between, when another user tries to edit the same row, he would get a message.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html search for `for update`

Comment: So is this question answered?

Answer (score 4):

Locks are released at the end of a transaction. So you need to keep the transaction *open* to uphold the lock and do everything in a single transaction:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM personnel WHERE id = 12 FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;  -- row level locking
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
UPDATE personnel SET ...
WHERE id = 12;
COMMIT;
```

Alternatively you can use the somewhat less restrictive `FOR SHARE` clause.
[Details in the manual on `SELECT` in the chapter "The Locking Clause".](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)

Concurrent reads are *allowed*. Quoting the chapter ["Row-level Locks" in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS):

> In addition to table-level locks, there are row-level locks, which can
> be exclusive or shared locks. An exclusive row-level lock on a
> specific row is automatically acquired when the row is updated or
> deleted. The lock is held until the transaction commits or rolls back,
> just like table-level locks. Row-level locks do not affect data
> querying; they block only **writers to the same row**.

To have concurrent attempts to do the same fail immediately, use the **`NOWAIT`** option - for *all* competing queries.

Comment: After I do the `SELECT` I can still access that row from another psql terminal. This shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Ok `FOR UPDATE` blocks new updates regarding that row, but is it not possible to block that row even from `SELECT`?

Comment: @Saphire: Yes, that's by design. Concurrent reads are allowed.

Comment: So how could I realize my goal in the question then?

Comment: @Saphire: Wasn't your declared goal to `circumvent double-writes`? That is achieved. A concurrent transaction will not be able to lock the same row (or modify it) until your transaction is done.

Comment: I mean this _In the time between, when another user tries to edit the same row, he would get a message._

Comment: @Saphire: Another user should be using the **same code** and will have to wait until the lock is released (the first transaction finishes) or run into a timeout. If you don't want to wait, but get an error message, use `NOWAIT`.